# Frame buffers and rendering

Tags: opengl

In the orange book

> The region of graphics memory that is modified as a result of OpenGL rendering is called the
>   FRAME BUFFER

What is the rest of the graphics memory being used for that is not modified by OpenGL rendering?

Comment: Storing textures, compiled shader programs, vertex data, entire scenes, etc. Theres's a reason GPUs come with 8GB+ of memory even though they only need an 8MB frame-buffer for a 1920x1080x32bpp display size.

Comment: Not to mention that GPUs hardly ever run in "exclusive" mode anymore - so your GPU memory will also contain buffers for your composited desktop/window manager and other system services (such as rasterized fonts).